# CSS Styles - Editing H2 within classes

Tags: css, class, tags, edit

I'm looking to edit the content of a H2 class within another block of classes but struggling to make it work.

Here is the class list

```
<header class="mainHeader">
            <li id="xyz_insert_html_widget-2" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-last widget-odd widget widget_xyz_insert_html_widget "><h2 class="box">Live Now - Podcasts</h2>
```

I'm trying to edit the content of the H2 which contains "Live Now - Podcasts" with no luck

I've tried a lot of things with no avail, the last thing I tried was

```
#mainHeader li#xyz_insert_html_widget-2.widget-1.widget-first.widget-last.widget-odd.widget.widget_xyz_insert_html_widget h2.box
```

Using the content property `content: "TEXT HERE";`

Any help in pointing me in the right direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.box{
   content: "TEXT HERE";
}
```

This because with css you can just reference the specific element class name that you want your properties to apply unless you have those on other area of your documents. 
In that case either assign an id to it so to reference it like this:

```
#exampleid{
    content: "TEXT HERE";
}
```

or following your line, being case specific:

```
header > li > .box {
    content: "TEXT HERE";
}
```

Comment: Marco your response worked perfectly, thank you for helping me resolve my issue!